# Correct term for describing how "interesting" a stock is to buy

Tags: portfolio, shares

When I decide what stocks to place in my portfolio I do a series of technical and fundamental analyses and during each one I give stocks different numbers of "points", and I basically go for the ones which I've given the highest rating in the end.
What I'm wondering is, is there some term for this rating? Stockbrokers probably have some kind of word for it?

The main reason why I'm asking this is that I'm programming an automating app for this process and I really can't think of anything good to name the variable.

Comment: They use words like Strong Buy, Buy, Hold, Sell, Strong Sell. I'm commenting, not answering, as this question is likely to be closed as off-topic. It's actually not a personal finance issue, per se.

Comment: Alright. Thank you. Point taken. I asked on english.stackexchange.com instead

Comment: Most welcome. Hopefully my comment worked to answer your question.

Comment: Try using highest rated stock, after all you are rating the stocks not recommending them.

Comment: "is there some term for this rating" - how about 'Rating'?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about personal finance

Comment: "Sentiment" describes your likelihood to buy, hold, sell, etc.

Comment: This might be more on-topic over at [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not about personal finance

Comment: I believe the word you want is simply ***RATING***.  But it's a question for the ELU site, not here, heh!

Answer (score 2):

You can call it a stock rating of say between 0 to 5 or 0 to 10 or whatever scale you want to use.

It should not be called a recommendation but rather a rating based on the criterial you have analysed.

Also a scale from say 0 to 5 is better than using terms like buy, hold and sell.

Comment: I have a similar rating system for my stock screener. The parameters that make up the points are my own personal opinions of what makes a stock a 10 or 0. Do you know of a way to test my rating system to see if there is any validity  or if it just biased to my opinions.

Comment: @NuWin Look up the term [backtesting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtesting).

Comment: right, just "Rating" is the term the OP should use on his app.  Simple.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I am aware of backtesting. Just wanted to ask if there were any other ways to test because results from backtesting can be biased too :)

Comment: @NuWin - the only way the results from backtesting would be biased is if you don't use a standard set of rules to do the bactesting. Any backtesting on a Rules Based System (RBS) will work just as it should and will not be biased, but if you start making biased decisions during the backtesting (i.e. taking trades when the RBS usually wouldn't or not taking a trade when the RBS would, just because you can see what will happen in the future) - then the backtesting will be biased and frankly useless.